# javascript initialize function to the appended element only

Tags: javascript, initialization, append

I have to reinitialize a function once the elements were appended because the function won't work to the appended element when not reinitialized.

```
function reinitialize()
{        
    //code sample
    alert('call me only once');
}
```

The problem is, for example there are element appended more times let say 4x

The reinitialize() will then be called 4x which will then give a result from the example above

```
call me only once
call me only once
call me only once
call me only once
```

So I am thinking that I must reinitialize ONLY that function to the elements that is going to be appended.

How to deal with this?

Comment: Simply pass the appended elements as parameters.

Comment: Why would you need to reinitiailize the function? Rather fix that problem. Probably you want to use event delegation (tell us what your function does).

Comment: @Bergi, too many to tell. If I'm going to fix the first problem which is "function not working with the appended elements" how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a function that runs only once, like this (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DeNTr/):

```
(function(){
  var hasRun = false;
   window.reinitialize = function(){
     if (hasRun) {
        return;
     }
     console.log("running...");
     //stuff
     hasRun = true;
  }

})();

reinitialize (); // prints running...
reinitialize (); //does nothing
```